# Trying to migrate an install

Tags: drupal, migration

EDIT: OK... I followed the instructions in the link that's in my comment, but I'm back at exactly the situation described below in OP. I guess that's good - at least there's some consistent thing wrong. I did the whole from-zero fresh install of Drupal and CiviCRM again, and this time, on the subsequent db restore, instead of dropping the existing, fresh db first, I left the db in place and truncated tables and reloaded them with the backup data. Didn't make any difference. Any help with this is HIGHLY appreciated!

--

I've got a CiviCRM 5.10.4 install (yeah, I know, old - it will be brought up to date as soon as I solve the present problem) running on Drupal 7.67, and I want to migrate the whole thing to a different hosting platform. Specifically, I'm moving from a platform where I don't have shell access, and also direct admin access to the db, to one where I do have both (RHEL7 Linux and MySQL)

Briefly: I tried just taking a gzip of the filesystem tree and a dump of the db, and putting these in their new places, but it didn't work. Can't quite remember what error I saw, now. Yes, my database settings in the Drupal settings are correct, and I've looked in the `civicrm.settings.php` as well, and don't see anything that raises any flags yet.

So next, I tried doing a fresh install of Drupal 7.67 and Civi 5.10.4 on the new platform. That fresh install worked fine. So THEN I tried wiping out the fresh clean database, and restoring it with the backup from my production system.

**What happens now is that I can get the Drupal login screen, but when I try to login, I get a 404. Specifically, it's trying to redirect me to `/node?destination=node`, and I'm not sure what this means.** I try entering URL `/civicrm/dashboard` by hand (*deliberately only giving relative URLs here, figuring my domain part is irrelevant*), but I still get 404 (`The requested URL /civicrm/dashboard was not found on this server`). I'm a noob at Apache configuration, so I'm not sure if this could be caused by the web server. I have carefully set the filesystem permissions also for best security, using good advice found on the web. I have a feeling this is not caused by the permissions, but am open to anything :)

I have a feeling I just need to tweak something, either in the db or the filesystem or both, and it'll work, but have no clue what or where. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Geh, just discovered https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers, by clicking on one of the links on the right. Not sure why SE didn't show me that one when I first started typing my question. Will delete this if that answers my problem.

Comment: I think SE only searches within itself and your link is in the docs area.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but I clicked on an SE link on the right sidebar, which led me to someone's question in which the quoted CiviCRM docs link was given.